# Symfony2 SSL certificate, verify that the CA cert is OK. error:14090086

Tags: symfony, ssl, curl, payum

I got an error on my local test server:

> SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

I'm using standard Symfony 2.5 + Payum payment bundle with paypal express checkout. Error comes when payum trying to do payment action. As i understand, payum using, to sent information, standard symfony http request api. And that api then looks like using Buzz Client(cURL) that located here:

> symfony\vendor\kriswallsmith\buzz\lib\Buzz\Client\Curl.php

I didn't intall it. That Buzz Client comes as part of symfony it self. And i didn't found any options available to be able to configure it.

I already red this: [Symfony2 : send a HTTP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620024/symfony2-send-a-http-request)
For me it's not working.

Because in my case, Buzz Client is a part of symfony api request and how to configure exactly it, i didn't found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is described here: https://github.com/Payum/Payum/issues/233. Long story short: There was a security bug in SSL and PayPal desided to disable old version and allow only new one. They did a BC break.

Here you may find some additional info: https://github.com/Payum/Payum/issues/250, https://github.com/Payum/Payum/pull/237